# getting an "Failed to create the Crystal Query Engine." error on deployed server

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

i am using asp.net 3.5 with c# ajax toolkit and linq the crystal report working fine on local machine and visual stedio 2008 on server but when i deplyed on iis 7 i got following exceptions

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\basicSaleReport {DDE751B0-9A36-4A9C-83C5-D5BAC6274B16}.rpt:
Failed to create the Crystal Query Engine.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\basicSaleReport {DDE751B0-9A36-4A9C-83C5-D5BAC6274B16}.rpt:
Failed to create the Crystal Query Engine.

Source Error: 


Line 40:             //Response.Write(Server.MapPath("basicSaleReport.rpt"));
Line 41:             //Response.End();
Line 42: report.Load(Server.MapPath("basicSaleReport.rpt"), OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy); Line 43:             report.SetDataSource(ds);
Line 44:             NoiseMatch.DAL.NoisematchDataContext DC=new NoiseMatch.DAL.NoisematchDataContext();

Source File: C:\inetpub\vhosts\Reservations.noisematch.com\httpdocs\Admin\SaleReport.aspx.cs    Line: 42 

Stack Trace: 


[COMException (0x800002d8): Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\basicSaleReport {DDE751B0-9A36-4A9C-83C5-D5BAC6274B16}.rpt:
Failed to create the Crystal Query Engine.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +0
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +95
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +271

[CrystalReportsException: Load report failed.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +333
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) +893
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod) +85
   NoiseMatch.Admin.SaleReport.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\vhosts\Reservations.noisematch.com\httpdocs\Admin\SaleReport.aspx.cs:42
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4211; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4209
```

plz help me out thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the issue is that you did not deploy and install the Crystal Reports Merge Module with your application.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225386%28VS.80%29.aspx) for more information.